# How to perform linear regression with categorical factors?

Tags: regression, categorical-data, software, continuous-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test the statistical significance for categorical variable in linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31690/how-to-test-the-statistical-significance-for-categorical-variable-in-linear-regr)

I need to perform a multiple regression analysis. My dependent variable or "response" is a continuous/quantitative variable. I have several independent variables or "factors" and they are all categorical. I'm wondering what method/software would best suit my needs.

Comment: Can you say more about what you'd like to know? (This question is fairly simple / sparse.) You may also be interested in [this recent question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31690/how-to-test-the-statistical-significance-for-categorical-variable-in-linear-regr).

Comment: good catch, @gung. I thought this sounded familiar. I voted to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary linear regression should be fine for this.  A categorical variable can be expressed through a set of dummy variables.  In SAS you could use proc reg or proc glm.  I am sure that R, STATA, minitab and SPSS also have similar ways to run such a model.

Comment: To add to Michael's reply, in R you can use the lm() function.  In Stata, you can use the regress function.