# How to interpret p-values for factors

Tags: r, categorical-data, generalized-linear-model, p-value

I have fitted a Poisson model to my data in R which includes two factors as independent variables. Each factor has 5 levels. I have used the  `contrasts = list(FactorA='contr.sum', FactorB='contr.sum')`command to change the constraints of my model. So, the parameter estimates for each factor sum to 1.

My problem is that I find it very difficult to understand what exactly the p-values of the estimates mean. For instance, if the p-value for one level of `FactorA` is significant, does this mean that it's generally significant for explaining the response variable or only in comparison to the other levels of the same factor?

Are the constraints that I used involved in this interpretation that I have to make for the significance of each level?

Also, I do not get any output for the last level of each factor. Is there any way to interpret those two levels?

Comment: Sorry, parameter estimates sum to 0 (not 1).

Comment: When presented with a categorical variable, the GLM does pairwise comparisons against some base reference level to all the other levels. So if you have 5 levels in your categorical variable, the glm would compare lvl 1 and 2, lvl 1 and 3.. and so on. As to what levels are significant, there's a post [here][1] that may help.


  [1]: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31690/how-to-test-the-statistical-significance-for-categorical-variable-in-linear-regr