# Test significance of categorical variable with multiple levels, when model also includes interactions

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I am fitting a mixed model with the command

```
model=lmer(Activity ~ 1 + Novelty*Valence*ROI + (1 | Subject))
```

Activity is a measure of brain activity, Novelty and Valence are categorical variables coding the type of stimulus used to elicit the response and ROI is a categorical variable coding three regions of the brain that we have sampled this activity from. Subject is an ID number for the individuals the data was sampled from (n=94).

In attempting to get a single estimate for ROI (since it has 3 levels), I ran

```
model_test=lmer(Activity ~ 1 + Novelty*Valence*ROI - ROI + (1 | Subject))
anova(model,model_test)
```

The output of my anova command suggests these models are equivalent

```
object: Activity ~ 1 + Novelty * Valence * ROI + (1 | Subject)
..1: Activity ~ 1 + Novelty * Valence * ROI - ROI + (1 | Subject)
       Df     AIC     BIC logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
object 14 -721.88 -641.78 374.94  -749.88                        
..1    14 -721.88 -641.78 374.94  -749.88     0      0          1
```

Playing around with different models, this seems to happen any time I eliminate an effect or interaction that is qualified by a higher-order interaction. What is the correct way to get an estimate for this categorical variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have encountered is that by removing the main effect for `ROI` in the model formulation, you have simply reparameterized the model. The main effect is still there, but now it just appears as part of the interaction. For example:

```
> dt <- read.csv("http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/politeness_data.csv")
> 
> lm0 <- lm(frequency ~ attitude*gender, data=dt)
> lm1 <- lm(frequency ~ attitude*gender - gender, data=dt)
> 
>summary(lm0)

Call:
lm(formula = frequency ~ attitude * gender, data = dt)

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          260.686      7.784  33.491   <2e-16 ***
attitudepol          -27.400     11.008  -2.489   0.0149 *  
genderM             -116.195     11.008 -10.556   <2e-16 ***
attitudepol:genderM   15.890     15.664   1.014   0.3135    

Residual standard error: 35.67 on 79 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7147,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7038 
F-statistic: 65.95 on 3 and 79 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> summary(lm1)

Call:
lm(formula = frequency ~ attitude * gender - gender, data = dt)

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          260.686      7.784  33.491  < 2e-16 ***
attitudepol          -27.400     11.008  -2.489   0.0149 *  
attitudeinf:genderM -116.195     11.008 -10.556  < 2e-16 ***
attitudepol:genderM -100.306     11.144  -9.000 9.71e-14 ***

Residual standard error: 35.67 on 79 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7147,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7038 
F-statistic: 65.95 on 3 and 79 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Note that the main effect for `gender` in `lm0` is now shown as the interaction term `attitudeinf:genderM` in `lm1`. This is because there are only 2 levels of `gender`. If we had more than 2 levels of a categorical variable and removed it's main effect, the interaction terms would then be simple contrasts. Note also that the estimate for the interaction parameter in `lm0` is now the *difference* in the two levels of the interaction in `lm1`

The $R^2$, F statistic and the associated degrees of freedom are identical in both models, because they are simply different parameterizations of the same model.

In order to test the significance of `gender` we need to remove it from the interaction as well. Since this example is a two-way interaction, we need to remove the interaction entirely:

```
> lm3 <- lm(frequency ~ attitude, data=dt)
> anova(lm0,lm3)

Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: frequency ~ attitude * gender
Model 2: frequency ~ attitude
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F    Pr(>F)    
1     79 100511                                  
2     81 345341 -2   -244830 96.216 < 2.2e-16 ***
```

Also see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31690/how-to-test-the-statistical-significance-for-categorical-variable-in-linear-regr) for more details about testing the significance of a categorical variable.