# ANOVA is not significant. If I exclude one factor level it gets significant

Tags: anova, psychology

I asked participants of a survey to rate the competence of 10 stimuli and want to see whether the stimuli differ significantly. I conducted a repeated measurements ANOVA and tested whether competence ratings significantly differs as a function of stimuli. It was not significant. Then I excluded two stimuli from the ANOVA and it became significant. How is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test the statistical significance for categorical variable in linear regression?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31690/how-to-test-the-statistical-significance-for-categorical-variable-in-linear-regr)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, the questions are clearly *related*, but I'm not sure that's an obvious duplicate.

Comment: Then there are other very similar posts which are better candidates for duplicates!