# Overall effect for non-binary categorical variable, Cox

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, anova, survival, cox-model

There are many great answers on Cross-Validated explaining that the `p-values` for `cox.zph` (or other regression models) in R refer to the difference between a factor level and its reference ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502758/interpretation-of-p-values-for-each-level-of-a-covariate) & [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31690/how-to-test-the-statistical-significance-for-categorical-variable-in-linear-regr), for example).

If one desires to get the overall significance of the categorical variable as a whole (as in the top row of the output in the question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483263/how-to-decide-if-categorical-variable-is-significant-in-cox-regression-spss), for example), [it seems](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31690/how-to-test-the-statistical-significance-for-categorical-variable-in-linear-regr) tests (ANOVA & log-likelihood ratio test) with and without the categorical variable or should be performed.

I have about 20 non-binary categorical variables; do I really have to fit all of these one-by-one to get an idea about whether a non-binary predictor is really important for the model? This seems wrong.

I tried using `rms::anova()` as suggested in the top comment on [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/502758/interpretation-of-p-values-for-each-level-of-a-covariate) but I am met with 50+ errors that are all either `one or more coefficients may be infinite` or `Ran out of iterations and did not converge`

Comment: The errors/warnings suggest that the problem is with your model rather than with the post-model `anova()` calculation. I suspect that there are some combinations of predictor values that don't have any events. The Wald-test of `rms::anova()` needs a proper covariance matrix among the coefficient estimates (e.g., available via the `vcov()` function). If your original model is not converging and you have "infinite" estimates of coefficients, then you won't have the necessary covariance matrix.

Comment: That could definitely be possible because I added many strata terms to account for nonproportionality. But now that leaves me with some trouble to deal with this issue