# Interaction effect no significant in regression but significant in predicted values

Tags: r, least-squares, interaction

I have a question regarding statistical significance in an OLS model with an interaction.

Basically, when I plot the predicted values, the interaction is **significant** as shown in the Figure below but is **not** in the regression table.

I study the changes in an outcome `y` over 4 time periods (the x-axis on the plot `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`). I have a dummy variable `D` and I want to know if there is a differential increase of `y` by `D` over the 4 time points.

I have a simple interaction OLS model with $y_{i} = \alpha + \beta_{1} time_{i} \times \beta_{2} D_{i} + \epsilon_{i}$

[image]

In the regression table, the interaction is not significant but on the plot it is. **Why?**

[image]

I simulated as best as I could my data

```
library(tidy verse)
library(ggeffects)

set.seed(125)

y1_0 = rnorm(10, 100, 30)
y2_0 = rnorm(20, 105, 40)
y3_0 = rnorm(60, 140, 50)
y4_0 = rnorm(70, 160, 60)

y1a = data.frame(y = y1_0) %>% mutate(time = 't1')
y2a = data.frame(y = y2_0) %>% mutate(time = 't2')
y3a = data.frame(y = y3_0) %>% mutate(time = 't3')
y4a = data.frame(y = y4_0) %>% mutate(time = 't4')

y1_1 = rnorm(20, 105, 30)
y2_1 = rnorm(20, 110, 40)
y3_1 = rnorm(60, 160, 50)
y4_1 = rnorm(70, 200, 60)

y1b = data.frame(y = y1_1) %>% mutate(time = 't1')
y2b = data.frame(y = y2_1) %>% mutate(time = 't2')
y3b = data.frame(y = y3_1) %>% mutate(time = 't3')
y4b = data.frame(y = y4_1) %>% mutate(time = 't4')

y0 = bind_rows(y1a, y2a, y3a, y4a)
y1 = bind_rows(y1b, y2b, y3b, y4b)

y0$d = 0
y1$d = 1

df = bind_rows(y0, y1)
df = as_tibble(df)

model = lm(y~time*d, df)
summary(model)

gg = ggpredict(model, terms = c('time', 'd'))
gg = as.data.frame(gg)

gg %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, predicted, colour = group, group = group)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), width = 0.2) +
  geom_point(size = 3) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'blue4'))
```

Answer (score 2):

> the interaction is significant as shown in the Figure below but is not in the regression table.

The regression table by itself does not represent the significance of a multi-level categorical predictor. That's the case whether there's an interaction or not.

The "significance" of the individual interaction coefficients represents whether each of them is individually different from a value of 0. That doesn't, however, examine whether the interaction term *as a whole* is significant. For that you need something beyond the coefficient table.

You can see the source of confusion by simply resetting the reference level for the categorical predictor `time`.

```
df$time<-factor(df$time)
df2<-df
df2$time <- relevel(df2$time,ref="t4")
model2 <- lm(y~time*d,data=df2)
summary(model2)
## extract to match what's shown in OP
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
## (Intercept)  161.033      6.401  25.158  < 2e-16 ***
## timet1       -59.437     18.104  -3.283 0.001140 ** 
## timet2       -47.435     13.578  -3.494 0.000543 ***
## timet3       -17.120      9.422  -1.817 0.070140 .  
## d             34.821      9.052   3.847 0.000144 ***
## timet1:d     -26.644     22.630  -1.177 0.239910    
## timet2:d     -42.702     19.202  -2.224 0.026856 *  
## timet3:d     -29.046     13.324  -2.180 0.029985 *
```

ALL of the coefficient estimates including the intercept have been changed from the model in the question. Two of the interaction coefficients are now "significant" by the p < 0.05 criterion.

Yet all we have done is change the reference level of one categorical predictor.

If a predictor is involved in an interaction, its "main effect" coefficient estimate (with default treatment/dummy coding) is for the situation when all its *interacting* predictors are at 0 (continuous predictors) or the reference level (categorical predictors). That principle extends to the intercept and to interaction terms involving multi-category predictors, too.*

Re-centering/re-ordering one predictor will affect the regression coefficient estimates of any other predictors with which it interacts. That's frequently overlooked and a massive source of confusion, base on how many such questions we see on this site.

The two models are functionally identical, as one should expect. Predictions take into account the model-specific coefficient estimates and their covariances so that predictions for any particular choice of predictor values are the same. Here are predictions for all 8 combinations of `time` and `d`, from both models.

```
 predict(model,data.frame(time=rep(c("t1","t2","t3","t4"),2),d=rep(c(0,1),times=c(4,4))))
##        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
## 101.5968 113.5979 143.9137 161.0333 109.7737 105.7174 149.6889 195.8546 
 predict(model2,data.frame(time=rep(c("t1","t2","t3","t4"),2),d=rep(c(0,1),times=c(4,4))))
##        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
## 101.5968 113.5979 143.9137 161.0333 109.7737 105.7174 149.6889 195.8546
```

The models have identical overall significance, as shown by `anova()`

```
anova(model)
## Analysis of Variance Table
## 
## Response: y
##            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
## time        3 233474   77825 27.1367 1.133e-15 ***
## d           1  22906   22906  7.9870  0.005006 ** 
## time:d      3  21600    7200  2.5106  0.058686 .  
## Residuals 322 923458    2868                      

anova(model2)
## Analysis of Variance Table
## 
## Response: y
##            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
## time        3 233474   77825 27.1367 1.133e-15 ***
## d           1  22906   22906  7.9870  0.005006 ** 
## time:d      3  21600    7200  2.5106  0.058686 .  
## Residuals 322 923458    2868
```

Note that in these simulated data the overall interaction coefficient isn't quite "significant" by the usual arbitrary p < 0.05 criterion. If there were particular pre-specified combinations of `time` and `d` of interest, however, you could make those comparisons without worrying about the lack of "significance."

[This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/31690/28500) shows how to use a likelihood-ratio test between 2 models to examine the overall significance of a multi-category predictor. The same principle applies here with the interaction: compare the models with and without the interaction term to get the best estimate of the overall "significance" of the interaction.

```
modelAdditive <- lm(y~time+d,data=df)
anova(modelAdditive,model)
## Analysis of Variance Table
## 
## Model 1: y ~ time + d
## Model 2: y ~ time * d
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
## 1    325 945058                              
## 2    322 923458  3     21600 2.5106 0.05869 .
```

In this case the result is the same as seen for the interaction term in the single model. With multiple interactions or levels of interactions, however, the problems with the [type of ANOVA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13241/28500) and the listed order of variables can lead to further confusion.

[This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27429/28500) illustrates a "chunk test" approach, tests that examine all coefficients involving each set of predictors/interactions together. That's a very general approach that doesn't require re-fitting the model and directly evaluates all non-linear terms and interactions in the model. It's implemented in the `anova()` function that's specific to models generated by the [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) in R.

```
library(rms)
modelOLS = ols(y~time*d, df)
anova(modelOLS)
##                 Analysis of Variance          Response: y 
## 
##  Factor                                  d.f. Partial SS MS        F     P     
##  time  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)       6  262146.28  43691.047 15.23 <.0001
##   All Interactions                         3   21600.10   7200.034  2.51 0.0587
##  d  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)          4   44505.75  11126.437  3.88 0.0043
##   All Interactions                         3   21600.10   7200.034  2.51 0.0587
##  time * d  (Factor+Higher Order Factors)   3   21600.10   7200.034  2.51 0.0587
##  REGRESSION                                7  277980.02  39711.432 13.85 <.0001
##  ERROR                                   322  923458.15   2867.882
```

In my experience the "chunk" tests are least likely to lead to confusion with more complicated models, particularly those that go beyond ordinary least squares.

---

*An interaction coefficient under treatment/dummy coding represents the *difference* from what might have been predicted based solely on the intercept, "main effects," and lower-level interactions. All those are changed in `model2` from `model`. Note that the `timet1:d` coefficient in `model2` is the negative of the `timet4:d` coefficient in `model`. That's because the reference roles of `timet1` and `timet4` have switched between the two model.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know that.

Comment: But if the interaction is important from theoretical point of view, we want to have it in the model, we don't want to test its *whole* significance, but the significance of the levels, then is predicting values the only way to test for their significance?

Comment: @giac if the interaction is in a model then it does make sense to test its overall significance. That said, the best way I know to demonstrate the _importance_ of an interaction is to display predictions, based on the interaction, that you wouldn't have expected to see without the interaction. That seems to be what you did.

Comment: Would you be so kind to flesh out a bit more your answer, so I can award you the bounty. I think a lot of people are confused about this. Especially, I see a lot of people interpreting the significance of the coefficients' interaction in an ambivalent way. If an interaction is not significant, I dont think people will do the step of showing the predicting values.