# glmer problems in seeing all variables

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, interaction, binary-data, glmm

I am trying to run a binomial glmm to understand the relationship between various concentrations of a compound sensed by different castes of ants. We have 5 different compound concentrations (a-e), and 3 different castes (min, med, max). We tested this across 3 colonies (two, six, and seven) to see if they were interested in the compound (1 if yes, 0 if no). We listed id as the individual (there are 761).

Our data sheet is set up like this:

[image]

We used lme4 and the glmer command:

`m <- glmer(Y ~ Conc * (1 + Caste|Colony), data = d, family = binomial) summary(m, corr = FALSE)`

When we run this, the readout we get is:

```
    summary(m, corr = FALSE)
    Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood
    (Laplace Approximation) [glmerMod]
     Family: binomial  ( logit )
    Formula: Y ~ Conc * (1 + Caste | Colony)
    Data: d

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 1067.2   1118.1   -522.6   1045.2      750 

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
 -1.4844 -0.9855  0.7613  1.0076  1.4478 

  Random effects:
  Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr       
   Colony (Intercept) 0.4529   0.6730              
    Castemed    0.4387   0.6624   -1.00      
    Castemin    0.6416   0.8010   -1.00  1.00
   Number of obs: 761, groups:  Colony, 3

 Fixed effects:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
 (Intercept) -0.09754    0.16571  -0.589   0.5561  
 Concb       -0.05160    0.23068  -0.224   0.8230  
 Concc        0.21758    0.22971   0.947   0.3436  
 Concd        0.07658    0.23022   0.333   0.7394  
 Conce        0.52070    0.23263   2.238   0.0252 *
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
 optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
 boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

I do see concentration E as being significantly different than the others, however we are not seeing any of the interactions by caste and seem to be missing concentration A. I'm not sure if I need to add additional lines of code to get these interaction comparisons? I also would like to know if colony plays a role on the worker preference for the various concentrations. We are pretty sure that caste plays a role on perceptiveness (ie what concentration level they select for) however I feel like perhaps we are missing a key piece of the code to get this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have added these effects as random, there's only variance parameters estimated for them (listed under "random effects"). You also only asked for intercepts by caste, there isn't any interaction. A random effect always has a mean of zero.

Comment: I think the issue here is that R sets up contrasts for categorical (factor) predictors. There is surely a duplicate somewhere, but I can never find it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in the standard treatment (dummy) coding used in R, the `(Intercept)` is the estimate at the reference values of the predictors and the regression coefficients are the *differences* from that estimate associated with the predictors. These are the implications. (1) you aren't "missing concentration A"; that's included in the `(Intercept)`. (2) you do not "see concentration E as being significantly different than the others"; the coefficient for `concentration E` represents its difference only from the reference level (`concentration A`).

As you seem to be starting out with this type of analysis, learn to rely less on the summary reports of models and focus more on post-modeling tools that can evaluate results and predictions of models more generally. The [`car`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) and [`emmeans`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) packages are good examples that can work with mixed models.

Second, to elaborate on a comment from @PBulls: if you want to evaluate the association of `Caste` with outcome, you need to include it as a "fixed-effect" predictor in the model. If you also include it as a random slope (as in `(1 + Caste | Colony)`) you will get an estimate of the *variance* of the `Caste` effects among the `Colony` values. That's not strictly an interaction, but it is a measure of how much `Caste` effects differ among the `Colony` values.

Third, if you only have 3 values of `Colony` you probably should not be treating it as a random effect. See discussion on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/629864/28500) and its links. If you only have a small number of `Colony` values you might get what you seem to want with a simple binomial regression model with interactions:

```
glm(Y ~ Conc *  Caste * Colony, data = d, family="binomial")
```

That will require estimating 45 coefficients including the intercept. At first glance from your coefficient estimates it seems that you have similar numbers in the two `Y` outcome classes, so that shouldn't pose too much of a problem with overfitting, given your 761 observations.

If you are mostly interested in the `Conc *  Caste` interaction and just want to adjust for baseline differences among the levels of `Colony`, you could use a simpler model:

```
glm(Y ~ Conc *  Caste + Colony, data = d, family="binomial")
```

In the model summaries you will still *seem* to be missing values for the reference levels of the categorical predictors, but they will be subsumed in the values of `(Intercept)`. You will have to be careful when interpreting individual coefficients for predictors involved in interactions, as their values depend on the coding of the *predictors they interact with*. Those apparent problems, however, disappear when you do proper post-modeling analysis. [This page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/570725/28500) is one example of what's involved in models with interactions. That question is based on a standard linear regression model, but the principles apply in general.

Also, if you go to a model without random effects, you can do your work with the [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) in R, which nicely combines tools for modeling and post-model analysis.